# Hot Network Question suggests a question I'm already reading

Tags: bug, hot-questions

Very often when I click on a Hot Network Question the questions appear again on the HNQ while I'm reading it.

[image]

I bet there are enough hot questions to avoid showing the one you are already reading.

Comment: I don't know that this is even a bug, just a coincidence. Simple fix, refresh the page :)